# Attendance summarized report

Tags: sql-server, report

Due to company policies I cannot give the actual query I am working with but heres the breakdown and general idea. We have an attendance register that records for each day if an employee was at work or not and where the employee works at. I am trying to make a summary of this to say between this and that date the employee worked 5 shifts. The problem I am sitting with is that one particular employee worked in workplace A for 2 days and was then transferred to workplace B. After a few days at workplace B the employee was then transferred back to workplace A.

My results to my attempt has showed that the employee begun working at workplace A from 1-Jan and ended at 10-Jan with only 2 working shifts. I have a group by on the working place and the begin and end dates are a min and max selection.

```
SELECT att.Employee, att.Workplace, dte.BeginDate, dte.EndDate, shf.WorkShift FROM
(SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE WorkDate BETWEEN '1-Jan' AND '30-Jan') att
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(Shift) WorkShift FROM Attendance WHERE WorkDate BETWEEN '1-Jan' AND '30-Jan' AND Employee = att.Employee AND WorkPlace = att.WorkPlace AND Shift = 'Worked') shf
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(WorkDate) BeginDate, MIN(WorkDate) EndDate FROM Attendance WHERE WorkDate BETWEEN '1-Jan' AND '30-Jan' AND Employee = att.Employee AND WorkPlace = att.WorkPlace) dte
```

So this employees records should appear like this (I am sorry for the very bad grid, I don't know how to make it look pretty, you are more than welcome to edit it to look better)

```
| Name | Workplace  | beginDate | endDate | WorkShift |
| Jane | WorkPlaceA | 1-Jan     | 2-Jan   | 2         |
| Jane | WorkPlaceB | 3-Jan     | 8-Jan   | 5         |
| Jane | WorkPlaceA | 9-Jan     | 10-Jan  | 2         |
```

The attendance table looks something like this

```
| Name | Workplace  |  Date  | Shift  |
| Jane | WorkplaceA |  1-Jan | Worked |
| Jane | WorkplaceA |  2-Jan | Worked |
| Jane | WorkplaceB |  3-Jan | Worked |
| Jane | WorkplaceB |  4-Jan | Worked |
| Jane | WorkplaceB |  5-Jan | Worked |
| Jane | WorkplaceA |  6-Jan | Absent |
| Jane | WorkplaceA |  7-Jan | Absent |
| Jane | WorkplaceA |  8-Jan | Worked |
| Jane | WorkplaceB |  9-Jan | Worked |
| Jane | WorkplaceB | 10-Jan | Worked |
```

Comment: @Tanner I made the edit now, I realized I was missing that as soon as I started reading it over again. Thanks for the reminder though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish this using CTE's. Here is a sample working code that shows your expected values.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
SELECT Employee, WorkPlace, TransactionDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WorkPlace ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS WP,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS RN FROM Attendance WHERE Shift = 'Worked'),
    CTE2 AS (SELECT Employee, WorkPlace, TransactionDate, WP, RN, WP-RN AS GB FROM CTE1),
    CTE3 AS (SELECT Employee, WorkPlace, MIN(TransactionDate) AS TransactionDate, COUNT(1) AS Shifts FROM CTE2 GROUP BY Employee, WorkPlace, GB)

SELECT Employee, WorkPlace, TransactionDate AS [Start Date], DATEADD(DAY,Shifts - 1,TransactionDate) AS [End Date], Shifts FROM CTE3 ORDER BY TransactionDate ASC
```

Comment: That is working almost 100%, the problem is when the employee goes over from a worked shift to an absent shift. The EndDate stops at the first Absent shift. Any way to get around that. It should be showing the begin and end dates for when the employee was in a workplace regardless if they were actually working or not

Comment: While this is not the final solution I used to get what I needed this did help me to the right solution. And this did answer my question. thanks @Randolph

Answer (score 0):

I think your given output is wrong.

I think the way you are populating table is wrong.

Check my query,it can be further optmize,it do not count absent days

```
declare @t table(Name varchar(100),Workplace varchar(100), AttnDate  date ,Shifts  varchar(100))
insert into @t values
('Jane','WorkplaceA',' 1-Jan-16','Worked')
,('Jane','WorkplaceA',' 2-Jan-16','Worked')
,('Jane','WorkplaceB',' 3-Jan-16','Worked')
,('Jane','WorkplaceB',' 4-Jan-16','Worked')
,('Jane','WorkplaceB',' 5-Jan-16','Worked')
,('Jane','WorkplaceA',' 6-Jan-16','Absent')
,('Jane','WorkplaceA',' 7-Jan-16','Absent')
,('Jane','WorkplaceA',' 8-Jan-16','Worked')
,('Jane','WorkplaceB',' 9-Jan-16','Worked')
,('Jane','WorkplaceB','10-Jan-16','Worked')

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'Jane'
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '01-Jan-16'
DECLARE @ToDate DATE = '31-Jan-16';

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY attndate
            ) rn
    FROM @t
    WHERE NAME = @Name
        AND (
            AttnDate BETWEEN @FromDate
                AND @ToDate
            )
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT A.NAME
        ,A.workplace
        ,A.AttnDate
        ,Shifts
        ,rn
        ,1 RN1
    FROM cte A
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.NAME
        ,a.workplace
        ,a.AttnDate
        ,a.Shifts
        ,CASE 
            WHEN a.workplace = b.workplace
                THEN b.rn
            ELSE b.rn + 1
            END rn
        ,RN1 + 1
    FROM CTE A
    INNER JOIN CTE1 b ON a.attndate > b.attndate
    WHERE a.rn = RN1 + 1
    )
    ,CTE2
AS (
    SELECT NAME
        ,Workplace
        ,AttnDate beginDate
        ,(
            SELECT max(AttnDate)
            FROM CTE1 b
            WHERE b.rn = a.rn
            ) endDate
        ,(
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM CTE1 b
            WHERE b.rn = a.rn
                AND Shifts = 'Worked'
            ) WorkShift
        ,rn
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY rn
            ) rn3
    FROM cte1 a
    )
SELECT NAME
    ,workplace
    ,beginDate
    ,endDate
    ,WorkShift
FROM cte2
WHERE rn3 = 1
```